# Transfer points and polygons from custom projection

Tags: javascript, openlayers, projection

I am building webApp with openlayers that contain a map that allowed insert edit and remove points, my map is now using “EPSG:4326" projection.
I have shp files and xlsx files that contain polygons and points that I need to insert as layer in the map.
The problem is that the shp files use 2309 projection , this is Israel tm grid projection that open layer doesn't recognize.
How do I transfer this points/polygons to the 4326 projection?
I found this: http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2039/html/
But I don't know if its can be helpful, or how...

Comment: How are going to serve shape files to the OpenLayers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert shp files to GML (or KML, or GeoJSON)

1. with commad ogr2ogr http://linux.die.net/man/1/ogr2ogr, it is possible to specify projection transformation as well.
2. with free Quantum GIS (qgis) application, example is [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33948/how-to-export-data-from-qgis-to-display-in-google-maps).

To import xlsx file to GML/KML you can use Quantum Gis as well. This is nice [tutorial](http://yuvan004.wordpress.com/2012/01/07/import-excel-data-coordinates-in-quantum-gis/).

If you choose to use GML with openlayers, see [documentation](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Format/GML-js.html), if you want to use KML see [documantation here](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Format/KML-js.html), but I would choose [GeoJSON](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Format/GeoJSON-js.html#OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON.OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON), because it is smaller, it can be natively read by JavaScript.